# How do you make an entire subdirectory use the same page template in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, templates, wordpress-theming

If I have a URL structure like:

```
site.com/some-page/sub-page
site.com/some-page/other-sub-page
```

How can I make it so that everything within the `some-page` sub-directory uses the `some-page.php` template that is set for the parent `some-page` page?

Note: ideally, the sub-directory pages aren't actual pages, so the page being loaded in WP is `some-page` which I'll then use the URL to determine in that template if I should load `sub-page` content or `other-sub-page` content

Comment: This one can help you. Change the template after checking "some-page" in url. .  https://tommcfarlin.com/programmatically-set-a-wordpress-template/

Comment: @tsdexter so these sub-pages will be child pages of the parent page.. and you want child pages to inherit the same template as of parent page?

Comment: @Mohsin no, ideally the pages don't exist, they are dynamic, the loaded page should be 'some-page'